# ¿Cómo seleccionar todos los elementos del tipo menos con el que se está procesando Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tenemos esto:

```js
$("input[type=text]").on("change", function () {

    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        //Deshabilitar (disabled) todos los otros input text que no sean este (this)
    } else {
        $("input[type=text]").prop("disabled", ""); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un método de `jQuery` llamado [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/). Lo que hace es eliminar el elemento o el selector que le pases de la selección. En tu caso podría ser así:

```
$("input[type='text']").not($(this)).prop("disabled", true);
```

Lo mejor es que cachees todos los inputs para que no estés seleccionándolos constantemente:

```js
var inputs = $("input[type='text']");

inputs.on("change", function() {

  var el = $(this);

  inputs.not(el).prop("disabled", el.val() === "");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. En 9 minutos te pongo como respuesta válida.

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado. Un saludo ;)

Comment: Gracias, lo de cachar todos los inputs es excelente idea, pues utilizo la misma selección como 4 veces. gracias

Comment: Es la mejor solución. Cada vez que haces una selección de `jQuery` se recorre el documento completo buscando los elementos que cumplen con dicha selección. Al cachear una selección, este trabajo lo realiza el navegador solo una vez.